# Unable to Add Refences in SSIS Script Task

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-datatools

**Hello**,

I have a particular problem with **SQL Server 2012 SSIS**. When I want to add a reference "Script Component", in order to use **FileSystemObjects**. The Visual Studio IDE simply doesn't add it. I'm doing the following:

```
1) Open Solution Explorer in Visual Studio
2) Right-click Solution
3) Select "Add Reference"
4) Look in .NET Tab
5) Select Script Component
6) Hit OK Button*
```

Even after these steps, the reference is not being added as I cannot **Import Scripting** in the header.